# Adding error class to Webform fields

Tags: 7, webforms, forms

I have a Webform which I'm validating implementing the _validate event (i.e. altering $form["#validate"] by adding a custom validator which accepts &$form and &$form_state).

In my code I have something like this:

```
if ($nombre && !CasabacaS3SValidaciones::validarLongitud($nombre, 30))
{
    form_set_error('columnas][datos_personales][nombre', t('El nombre no debe superar 30 carácteres'));
    //what should I put in THIS LINE, replacing this comment, to add the error class?
}
```

I **have no clue** about adding the "error" class (e.g. fields marked as required have class "required", and also class "error" when the field is not set). How can I alter the field (take this example field in the form_set_error and assume input variables are &$form and &$form_state) so I can add the error for display?

**NOTE**: I'm seeking to add the "error" class to the fields, and **NOT** to the wrapping divs (i.e. those divs having form-item class).

(If a quick solution involves themes, please attach a link so I can read about because i'm banging my head about drupal yet, i'm a total n00b :s).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a preprocess functions in your theme for this. You can add preprocess in your template.php.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_textfield(&$vars) { // OR preprocess_field.

  $vars['#attributes']['class'][] = 'test' ;
}
```

Check the `$vars` parameter for values that may help you determine the logic. For examples, just search your code base for `preprocess_textfield` or preprocess_field. For more inf

Comment: How do I install those theme handlers? Can you point me a link? (i.e. how to actually make "mytheme" to available to my forms).

Comment: I edited my answer. If you have not idea what a preprocess function is then I suggest you read some tutorials about the thmeing system in drupal. For preprocesses functions you can take a look here https://drupal.org/node/11811 And here https://drupal.org/node/223430

Comment: Still not getting a clear idea. Documentation did not help me.

Comment: found the current theme! but when i edit the template.php adding casabaca_preprocess_field(&$vars) { dpm($vars); }, and refreshing the cache, it does nothing (yes, casabaca.info is the theme name).